# Returning value from out modifier to a collection in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Let's suppose I receive a collection of strings from user. I need to convert them to GUID sequences for further processing. There is a chance, that user may enter invalid data (not correct GUID sequence), so I need to validate input. Additionally, I can run business-process if only all uploaded data are correct GUID values. Here is my code:

```
IEnumerable<string> userUploadedValues = /* some logic */;
bool canParseUserInputToGuid = userUploadedValues.All(p => Guid.TryParse(p, out var x));
if(canParseUserInputToGuid)
    var parsedUserInput = userUploadedValues.Select(p=> Guid.Parse(p));
```

This logic works pretty well, but I don't like it as actually I am doing work twice. In second line, `Guid.TryParse(p, out var x)` already writing parsed GUID sequence to the X variable. Is there an approach to combine validating and mapping logic - if sequence elements satisfy for condition (`All`) then map this elements to a new collection (`Select`) in one query? It is important for me also in terms of performance, as it is possible that client will send large amount of data (1, 000, 000+ elements)  and doing twice work here is a bit inefficient.

Comment: You don't need to use LINQ everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in one `Select`:

```
var parsedUserInput = userUploadedValues.Select(p => Guid.TryParse(p, out var x) ? x : default)
                                        .Where(p => p != default);
```

For this one, you need to be sure if there is no `Guid.Empty` input from the user.

Otherwise, you can return a nullable `Guid` if parsing doesn't succeed:

```
var parsedUserInput = userUploadedValues.Select(p => Guid.TryParse(p, out var x) ? x : default(Guid?))
                                        .Where(p => p != null);
```

Another solution by creating an extension method, for example:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Guid? ToGuid(this string arg)
    {
        Guid? result = null;
        if(Guid.TryParse(arg, out Guid guid))
            result = guid;
        return result;
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
var parsedUserInput2 = userUploadedValues.Select(p => p.ToGuid())
                                         .Where(p => p != null);
```

But keep in mind that in this cases, you will have a collection of nullable Guids.

Comment: That will remove any correctly-specified values of default(Guid) though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct, this will be useful if there is a requirement for guid to not be the default/empty one.

Comment: @JonSkeet Kind of updated, but I'm not sure about performance here.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any particular performance difference here. You could always change your original `Select` to just: `.Select(p => Guid.TryParse(p, out var x) ? x : default(Guid?))` that that would have the equivalent result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `out var x` variable will be `Guid.Empty` in the case where it is not a valid `Guid`. So you can just do this:

```
    IEnumerable<string> userUploadedValues = new[]
    {
        "guids.."
    };
    var maybeGuids = userUploadedValues.Select( x => {
                                                    Guid.TryParse( x, out var @guid );
                                                    return @guid;
                                                } );
    if ( maybeGuids.All( x => x != Guid.Empty ) )
    {
        //all the maybe guids are guids
    }
```

Comment: Except that then you reject every *explicitly-specified* Guid.Empty value.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the validation and conversion like below,

```
IEnumerable<string> userUploadedValues = /* some logic */;
var parsedGuids = userUploadedValues.Where(p => Guid.TryParse(p, out var x));
if(userUploadedValues.Count() != parsedGuids.Count())
{
    //Some conversion failed, 
}
```

If the count of both the lists same, then you have all the converted GUIDs in the parsedGuids.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the non-LINQ method is just easier to read and no longer.

```
var parsedUserInput = new List<string>();
foreach(var value in userUploadedValues)
{
    if (Guid.TryParse(value, out var x)) parsedUserInput.Add(x);
    else...
}
```